# Javax validation error when save a class which include ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I want to save Tesis class using entityManager.persist() method but I get following error.

Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: thymeleafexamples.layouts.acenta.Acenta.

```
@Entity
public class Tesis {
public Tesis(){

}

public Tesis(String adi, Acenta acenta) {
    this.adi = adi;
    this.acenta = acenta;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String adi;


@NotEmpty
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="acenta_id")
private Acenta acenta;
//GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Acenta implements java.io.Serializable {

public Acenta(String adi) {
    this.adi = adi;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String adi;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="acenta")
private Set<Tesis> tesiss;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Hibernate Validator's API [org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html) annotation

> "asserts that the annotated string, collection, map or array is not
>   null or empty"

Based on the above definition `Acenta` type is not a valid type to check. You may consider using [javax.validation.constraints.NotNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) annotation instead as it's valid for all types and moreover not vendor specific.